# Python get MAX value by area os a list in cordenates

Tags: python

hello id like to filter a list getting the higer value of that by area
example:

```
teste = [[150,150,250,250], [0,0,200,200]]

print(max(teste))
```

in this case its returning me `[150,150,250,250]`

but the area for this object is calculated by `w=x2-x1` and `h=y2-y1`
in my array the objects are in this order `[x1,y1,x2,y2]`

then the math calc for it will be

```
area = w * l
```

in this case the area of segundo list object is higer than the first.
how can i filter this array using my area calculation?

Comment: "but the area for this object is calculated by ..." I suggest you write a function that does this calculation. `max()` doesn't know how to do it automatically.

Comment: You can give this function as key to `max`, e.g. `max(teste, key=get_area)` with `def get_area(coord): return (coord[3]-coord[1])*(coord[2]-coord[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to write a function which can calculate the area of each array

```
test = [[150,150,250,250], [0,0,200,200]]

def calc_area(coord_list):
    w = coord_list[2] - coord_list[0]
    h = coord_list[3] - coord_list[1]
    return w * h
```

The next stage is to pass this function to the key parameter of max, allowing it to calculate the area of each list in test:

```
m = max(test, key=calc_area)
print(m)
```

The above prints out the second list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `key` on `max()` funciton.

```
teste = [[150,150,250,250], [0,0,200,200]]

def calc_area(item):
    return (item[2] - item[0]) * (item[3] - item[1])

print(max(teste, key=calc_area))
```